# PHP within HTML etiquette

Tags: php

This has been bothering me for quite some time and I want to know what the typical etiquette is when writing PHP code within HTML.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    $country_list = array("AF"=>"Afghanistan", "AL"=>"Albania", "DZ"=>"Algeria");

    echo '<div class="some-class">
              <font color="red">Just some text.</font>
              <select>';

    foreach($country_list as $country_code => $country_name) {
        echo '<option value="' . $country_code . '">' . $country_name;
    }

    echo '</select>
          </div>';

?>
```

This to me looks extremely ugly because of how the HTML isn't lined up and it's hard to work with something that doesn't look good.

Is there any way I can improve so that it looks better? Is there some sort of PHP etiquette when writing PHP code like this inline with HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody will see the actual source, except yourself. It's just a matter of taste and if it works for you, great. The only thing that others will see is the HTML output. As we say around where I live, *"this isn't a Fashion contest".* However, some may kick if shown in the form of a question. ;-)

Comment: The neatest way is to use javascript to seperate HTML from PHP entirely.

Comment: @Dave Your comment doesn't even make any sense.  You think there's no reason to generate dynamic pages ever?

Comment: Why would using javascript make it `less` dynamic? I've always used ajax to bridge server side to client side. Rather than mixing the two in the same file..I see no real down side. Other than having to learn to do it in the first place.

Comment: @Brad Barring simple stuff like this, he does have a point; disregarding browser capabilities, using JavaScript to build up the page's components is a viable approach.

Comment: @Dave Using AJAX to build something like a country list is possible, but it increases the load on your server as well.

Comment: @Jack how so ? you only send the data for the list, everything else is pretty much cached anyway. Unless you mean due to increase number of connections to the server? I would agree its a bit much for a trivial list though.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why you may want to render a page server-side.  And, doing the work client-side really doesn't give you any benefit from a template management standpoint.  Whether you are injecting data server-side or client-side, it doesn't matter... you still have to do it.  If you like editing the DOM, then build the DOM up server-side.  Your decision to move code client-side should be based on what your application does and how, not because of a misunderstanding of separating display logic from business logic.

Comment: I can't think of a reason that would have advantages doing it server side over client side.

Comment: Voting to re-open... this question is certainly not *primarily* opinion based.  There are certainly a couple correct answers, but not many, which is the case for just about every question on StackOverflow.

Comment: ***"primarily opinion-based"*** which is just that. There is no "set etiquette". If PHP and HTML and SQL and LMNOP/QRST and whatever other language is involved and can all get along while working well together, then let's leave it at that. Everyone has their (particular) style to write functional code (to a certain extent); the operative word here being "functional". We do need however to follow certain "guidelines" sure, yet Moe will say one thing, Larry another, and Curly well.... he's the `oddball` in that trio; he does what he wants (but... there's a method to his madness). ;-)

Comment: I should consider making it as an answer, should it be re-opened (which the process has already started) lol @Dave I stand at getting at least 5 DOWNVOTES, and 1 upvote. lol But I "stand by guns". ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- This isn't a question about code style, as much as it is about separation of logic from presentation.  The question is worded in such a way that person asking believes it is about code style, but the answer has more to do with properly structuring code.

Comment: From what I gathered by the way the OP worded the question, I took it as being an `esthetics` thing. *"...This to me looks extremely ugly"* and *"Is there any way I can improve so that it looks better?"*  @Brad

Comment: I guess that was my fault. What I meant to say, is there a standard to which people should follow?

Comment: Sure there are "standards" and guidelines to follow, however methods (style) are a completely `different animal` altogether. As per [`The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)`](http://www.w3.org/) where you will find a lot of information on many related subjects. @Bagwell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's common practice to separate your code that outputs the HTML (the "view") from your logic (typically in a "controller").  At a minimum, this can be done with PHP code that just handles output, but is usually done with a template engine, such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.basic.syntax.tpl).

A template engine can be overkill if you have a simple application.  In these cases, there are some things you can do to clean up your code:

- Disregard HTML indentation.  Only worry about your code indentation in PHP.  That's where it matters to you anyway.  If you need to use indented HTML, let your browser's developer tools worry about it.
- Avoid closing/opening PHP tags repeatedly.  Just stick to `echo`.  Again, if you need to mix PHP and HTML so much that you feel the need to repeatedly close/open PHP tags, consider a template engine.

Finally, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data you output into HTML to ensure that you are generating valid HTML, and avoiding certain kinds of XSS attack vulnerabilities.

Comment: I think this is a great question, and all the answers are enlightening. Given that all PHP code is processed prior to sending the html, wouldn't it be an advantage to put all the code together (referring to your 'avoid opening/closing PHP tags) with the exeption of <?php echo $aaaa ?> ?

Comment: @TimSPQR Not all PHP code is processed prior to sending the HTML.  That depends on the application and server configuration.  If you want to echo one variable into a document, I think it's fine to open/close tags, just like your example.  What you should avoid though is a ton of mixing between the two, such as in Vincent's answer.  That's a terrible mess... unreadable and problematic.

Comment: Oooooohhhh...I had assumed that all server side code was processes prior to passing the data to client. VERY interesting. I'll try to learn a bit more about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is all pretty subjective stuff, but you could consider only breaking into PHP when absolutely necessary:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <font color="red">Just some text.</font>
    <select>
<?php

    $country_list = array("AF"=>"Afghanistan", "AL"=>"Albania", "DZ"=>"Algeria");

    foreach ($country_list as $country_code => $country_name) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $country_code, $country_name);
    }

?>
</select>
</div>
```

*I shall assume your values don't need to be escaped here, i.e. no "naughty countries".*

Alternatively, there are template engines that can help you with it, such as [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/):

```
<div class="some-class">
    <font color="red">Just some text.</font>
    <select>
        <option tal:repeat="country countries" tal:attributes="value repeat/country/key" tal:content="country" />
</select>
</div>
```

PHP code:

```
$tal = new PHPTAL('path/to/template');
$tal->set('countries', $countries);
echo $tal->execute();
```

The nice thing here is that everything stays in HTML mode and you've separated display logic (how to show data) from business logic (how to generate it).

Answer (score 0):

this is what I usually do

```
<?php
    $country_list = array("AF"=>"Afghanistan", "AL"=>"Albania", "DZ"=>"Algeria");
    $countries = '';
     foreach($country_list as $country_code => $country_name) {
            $countries. = '<option value="' . $country_code . '">' . $country_name;
        }
?>
```

//html part

```
div class="some-class">
              <font color="red">Just some text.</font>
              <select name="country>
<?php echo $countries; ?>
</select>
</div
```

Comment: that code would only contain the last country in the array, you should declare countries before the loop, ie $countries = ''; then inside the loop it should read $countries .= etcetc.

Comment: Thanks I had forgotten about that

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this... I do it sometimes

```
<?php
$country_list = array("AF"=>"Afghanistan", "AL"=>"Albania", "DZ"=>"Algeria");
?>

<div class="some-class">
     <font color="red">Just some text.</font>
     <select>

           <?php foreach($country_list as $country_code => $country_name) { ?>
                 <option value="<?=$country_code?>"><?=$country_name?></option>
           <?php } ?>

      <select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about "etiquette" but echoing HTML may not be the best idea. Maybe something like this:

```
  <div class="some-class">
     Just some text
     <select>
     <?php
         foreach($country_list as $country_code => $country_name) {
     ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country_code;?>">
                 <?php echo $country_name; ?> 
            </option>
     <?php
         }
     ?>
    </select>
   </div>
```

So minimize echoing HTML tags.

Comment: I couldn't disagree with this approach more.  This makes your code a real mess, in my opinion.  If you disagree, you should explain why you think echoing HTML is a bad idea.

Comment: @Brad I just think that as much as possible you should separate logic from the template stuff. The HTML tags are part of the template code and the PHP code is part of the logic. So short of using some templating engine I like to minimize echoing HTML in the logic. Its the same reason why you avoid echoing HTML in a Java servlet for instance. Or why MVC frameworks spring up all over the place.

Comment: I this fragment, I would argue that the PHP code is part of the view, since it is helping to generate the HTML.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Your example makes the problem much worse.  You're not separating anything.  You're mixing your PHP and the HTML.  Just because you're no using `echo` in your syntax doesn't mean it's not still a mess to work through.  The indentation makes it even more complicated.  Nobody can glance through this code and immediately see what's going on.  PHP constructs, such as if block and foreach don't just stop because the PHP tag closes.